# Playing and controlling mp3 files in Python?

Tags: python, audio, mp3, audio-streaming

First things first, I am a Python beginner, with a typical C++/Java background for object oriented stuff.

I was convinced to try Python for this current endeavor I am working on, and so far I like it. One issue I am having though is finding a good mp3 module.

I have tried TkSnack, which installed and ran fine with no errors(as long as my audio device wasn't busy) but it could never actually produce a sound, it just did nothing... I went online for help, and was disappointed with the amount of documentation.

So I decided to switch. I tried PyMad because it is in the standard repositories for Ubuntu as well. There was even less documentation on this, but I could make it play a sound. The only problem is that it requires a loop to constantly write/play the audio buffer. This makes it particularly hairy to handle playback control(in my opinion) cause I would have to run this in a separate thread or process, and somehow control the seek position for pause and such. This is a little too low level for why I am using Python. I liked the simplicity of TkSnack for its easy commands like "mysound.play()" or "mysound.pause()" rather than controlling a loop.

I also looked at pyMedia, which looks like it is the most up to date with documentation, but I can't get it to install on my machine. I get a "gcc exited with value 1" error or something like that when running the "python setup.py build" command.

So I am looking for any suggestions or help on one of these modules, or a completely different one, that is high level and easy to use for mp3s(and preferably other formats too) I am trying to have basic playback control(pause, stop, skip, seek) and I may also be streaming files too eventually(if I ever get there).

**EDIT**: I like the python bindings for Gstreamer, but is this a cross-platform solution?? I forgot to mention that as a requirement. But I always just associated GStreamer with Linux, would this work on other OSs?

**EDIT**: Wikipedia says [yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I can't help you with PyMad or pyMedia, but I have other suggestions.

Existing music players written in Python:

- [Exaile](http://www.exaile.org/)
- [FUPlayer](http://fuplayer.org/)
- [Listen](http://listengnome.free.fr/)

All of the above use the [Python bindings](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) for the [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/) multimedia framework. Docs for the bindings are scarce, but check [here](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/index.html), [here](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/), [here](http://www.jonobacon.org/2006/08/28/getting-started-with-gstreamer-with-python/), and examples from the source distribution [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-python/tree/examples).

Comment: I like the idea of communicating with GStreamer, since thats how most audio/video programs work in linux already. But would it still be applicable if I wanted to make it cross-platform?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to deal with this, and from my research I think your best bets are [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org) and [pygame](http://www.pygame.org). They're interface packages with built-in a/v support.

Comment: pyglet looks promising, I'm a little too busy for the next couple days to try implementing with it. But I will let you know if I do.