# How to play mp3 file in python script?

Tags: python, mp3

I'm looking for a simple way to play an mp3 file in python script ... I tried the winsound built in library but it can only play .wav files ... can you help me please? and thank you :D

Comment: How about [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/languages.php)?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780711/playing-and-controlling-mp3-files-in-python

Answer (score 0):

See the Pyglet [tutorial](http://pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/simple_audio_playback.html) for audio. You'll need to install [Pyglet](http://pyglet.org/download.html) and [AVbin](http://avbin.github.io/AVbin/Home/Home.html).

Comment: Make sure to change the file extensions to `mp3` for that tutorial.

Comment: If you need help installing, let me know, and I can guide you through it.