# How do I play .MP3 files in Python?

Tags: python, mp3, pyglet

How do I play an MPs file in Python? I have tried

```
import os
os.system("start C:/thepathyouwant/file")
```

and every time I get the error: "couldn't locate file"
I am working on a text based RPG, and I only want to add an MP3 file for music.
I'm just starting out in Python, and don't know much about Pyglet. I attempted an install using the command line:

```
python setup.py install
```

In the "Run" window.

I also attempted to install pyglet.msi, but I recieved the error:

```
pyglet requires Python 2.4 or later. The installation will be aborted
```

running Python 2.7.9
running Windows 8

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path

Comment: Try running `setup.py` in a command prompt instead of the Run window. It should display some hopefully helpful error messages.

Comment: @MarcB almost certainly.

Comment: Most Windows commands require backslashes as the directory separator.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780711/playing-and-controlling-mp3-files-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use startfile function in os module to play your file.Consider this example:

```
import os
os.startfile('C:/Users/Aakash/Desktop/songs/Anime.mp3')
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I am using Python 3.5 in Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS)